# Can Twitter consume OpenID for login?

Tags: twitter, openid, twitter-oauth

I know I can use OpenID to log in to a Facebook account (Linked Accounts for the account in question). However, I'm not seeing if I can do something similar for Twitter. Does anyone know if Twitter can consume OpenID to log in? (I want to use my own OpenID Identity Provider.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Twitter will not let you log in via other websites.

Developers can authenticate users to their own websites via OAuth, which lets them use their Twitter account as a password. However, that's probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, Twitter uses OAuth for authentication.

Comment: OAuth is for authorization, not authentication, which is slightly different. Openid for example is for authentication.